# Visual Studio IDE 2022 Windows layout problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In my `Visual Studio IDE 2022` (not `VSCode`) I want to put windows (Tabs: `Solution Explorer` and `Git Changes`) like on the photo:

[image]

but in my case windows are pinned on the right side:

[image]

How can I fix it? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Click the tab on the right to open it. Then next to close there is a pin icon pointing to the right side. Click it, and it will stay open and move the tab with the name to the bottom.